# Why is my Gyazo image not showing on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, images, external-sources

I asked a question on Stack Overflow, but the *image* I included doesn’t show up. Instead I only get an image icon. I used [Gyazo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyazo) to upload the image. Is that site not allowed?

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72907912/how-can-i-dynamically-link-all-other-pages-on-all-sites-in-a-navbar-in-typo311).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the image uploader in the question itself. You don't link to an image, you instead link to a website where the image is present. You can see clearly because of the absence of a .jpg or .png extension on your link.

If you inspect the image in the link, and look for its source you will find:

https://i.gyazo.com/79416bfca558ca1350e6052e5abd6bbf.png

Using the appropriate markdown you can make that show:

[image]

A quick way to get this link would be to right click the image available in your [original Gyazo link](https://gyazo.com/79416bfca558ca1350e6052e5abd6bbf) and select "Copy image address".

Comment: Ah that makes sense. You already edited my Stackoverflow question too right? Thanks for your help :)